# Swift: Random notifications is not random

Tags: swift, random, swiftui, notifications, local

I have local notifcations working in my Apple Watch app. Setting the interval in houser and the save buttonis also working. The only thing that is not working is displaying a random message. It selects one of the three from the **randomText()** function and then one is repeated every "interval" time...
This is one file.

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

struct Nottie2: View {
    @AppStorage("notificationInterval") var notificationInterval: Int = 1
    @AppStorage("isSnoozed") var isSnoozed: Bool = false
    @AppStorage("isNotificationsEnabled") var isNotificationsEnabled: Bool = false
    @State private var borderColor = Color.orange
    @State private var buttonText = "Save"

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Toggle(isOn: $isNotificationsEnabled) {
            
            if isNotificationsEnabled {
                Text("Turn off")
            }else {
                Text("Turn on")
            }
        }
            .padding()
            .onChange(of: isNotificationsEnabled) { enabled in
                if enabled {
                    requestPermission()
                } else {
                    disableNotification()
                }
            }
        
        if isNotificationsEnabled {
            Picker("Notification Interval", selection: $notificationInterval) {
                ForEach(1...6, id: \.self) { interval in
                    Text("\(interval) hour\(interval > 1 ? "s" : "")")
                }
            }.frame(height: 60)
            .padding()
            
            Button(action: {
                enableNotification()
                self.buttonText = "Saving"
                self.borderColor = .green
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                    self.buttonText = "Saved"
                    self.borderColor = .green
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4) {
                    self.buttonText = "Save"
                    self.borderColor = .orange
                }
                
            })
            {
                Text(buttonText)
            }.foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(1)
                .frame(width: 75)
                .padding(7)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                        .stroke(borderColor, lineWidth: 2))
                .buttonStyle(.plain)
            
            
        }
    }
    .onAppear() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted, error in
            if granted {
                print("Permission granted")
            } else {
                print("Permission denied")
                isNotificationsEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }
    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: WKExtension.applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification)) { _ in
        if isSnoozed {
            enableNotification(snooze: true)
        }
    }
}
```

function to request the notification permissions

```
private func requestPermission() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted, error in
        if granted {
            print("Permission granted")
            enableNotification()
        } else {
            print("Permission denied")
            isNotificationsEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

randomText() is called. I think that the issue is somewhere here. I think it (I do not know how) clear the notification after it is dismissed

```
    private func enableNotification(snooze: Bool = false) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
//        content.title = "Notification Title"
        content.body = randomText()
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    
    var trigger: UNNotificationTrigger
    if snooze {
        trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 540, repeats: false)
    } else {
        trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval(notificationInterval * 3600), repeats: true)
    }
    
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "notification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
}
```

Function with an small array with random notifications texts.

```
func randomText() -> String {
    let words = ["Place", "Cat", "House"]
    return words[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(words.count)))]
}
```

Rest of the notification actions.

```
private func disableNotification() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: ["notification"])
}

private func snoozeNotification() {
    isSnoozed = true
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: ["notification"])
    enableNotification(snooze: true)
}

private func dismissNotification() {
    isSnoozed = false
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: ["notification"])
}

private func showNotificationActions() {
    let snoozeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "snooze", title: "Snooze", options: [])
    let dismissAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "dismiss", title: "Dismiss", options: [.destructive])
    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "notificationActions", actions: [snoozeAction, dismissAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
}
}

struct Nottie2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Nottie2()
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are using the same notification every time because the function `enableNotification` runs only once, when the user gives permission. You probably need to generate a new notification, calling again `content.body = randomText()`, every time the user dismisses the previous notification.

Comment: @HunterLion has described the problem but his solution won’t work. Your code is scheduling a notification with some piece of random text and asking for it to be repeated every hour. The same text will appear. You cannot rely on the user dismissing previous notifications so you will have to schedule multiple notifications, each one hour apart and each with their own random text. Note that iOS only allows you to schedule 64 notifications at once and attempting to schedule a 65th will result in one of the earlier ones being dropped.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! You directed me in the right direction. I'm testing now somethings and it might work. If that is the case i will Anser my question.

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

struct NotifyView: View {
    @AppStorage("isNotificationsEnabled") var isNotificationsEnabled: Bool = false

    @State private var interval = 1
        
    @State private var buttonText = "Save"
    @State private var borderColor = Color.orange
    
    let messages = [
        "Take a 5 minute walk.",
        "Drink a glass of water.",
        "Stretch your legs.",
        "Take deep breaths.",
        "Close your eyes and meditate for a minute.",
        "Do a few jumping jacks.",
        "Think of something you're grateful for.",
        "Write down your thoughts in a journal.",
        "Read a book for 5 minutes.",
        "Call a friend and say hello.",
        "Smile and relax your shoulders.",
        "Make a cup of tea and take a break.",
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Notifications:")
                .foregroundColor(.orange)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
            
            Toggle(isOn: $isNotificationsEnabled) {
                
                if isNotificationsEnabled {
                    Text("Turn off")
                }else {
                    Text("Turn on")
                }
            }
            .padding()
            
            if isNotificationsEnabled {
                
                Picker("Interval (hours)", selection: $interval) {
                    ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { i in
                        Text("\(i) hours")
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                .padding()
                .frame(height: 70)
                Button(action: {
                    scheduleNotifications()
                    self.buttonText = "Saving"
                    self.borderColor = .green
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                        self.buttonText = "Saved"
                        self.borderColor = .green
                    }
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4) {
                        self.buttonText = "Save"
                        self.borderColor = .orange
                    }
                    
                })
                {
                    Text(buttonText)
                }
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(1)
                .frame(width: 75)
                .padding(7)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                        .stroke(borderColor, lineWidth: 2))
                .buttonStyle(.plain)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func scheduleNotifications() {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { granted, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        
        center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        
        for i in 1...10 {
            let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0..<messages.count)
            let message = messages[randomIndex]
            
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = "Time to take a break!"
            content.body = message
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
            content.categoryIdentifier = "reminder"
            
            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval(i * interval * 3600), repeats: false)
            
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
            
            center.add(request) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NotifyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NotifyView()
    }
}
```